# Write protect property in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I have a model with a payload of type json.

**content.json**

```
...
"properties": {
    "payload": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": true
    }
  },
...
```

I would like to protect parts of it from being overwritten when updateAttributes is called.

```
  Content.beforeRemote('prototype.updateAttributes', function (ctx, unused, next) {
    if (ctx.instance && ctx.instance.contentTypeId === 'folder') {
      // TODO: Do not allow direct modification of the folder items (should use exposed API).
      // Strip writes to payload.items and payload.itemIds
    }
    next();
  });
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Neither

```
delete ctx.req.body.payload.items
```

nor

```
delete ctx.args.data.payload.items
```

nor

```
delete ctx.instance.payload.items
```

does what I want.

Do I have to override the updateAttributes method entirely?

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, there is no other way to overcome your problem without overriding `updateAttributes`.

I have a file called `override-defaults.js` in the `boot` folder, with the following code.

```
var overrideUpdateAttributes = function (Model, fields) {
  var updateAttributes = Model.prototype.updateAttributes;
  Model.prototype.updateAttributes = function (data, cb) {
    data = _.omit(data, fields);
    if (Object.keys(data).length) {
      updateAttributes.call(this, data, cb);
    }
    else {
      cb(utils.createError('Request body cannot be empty', 400));
    }
  };
};

module.exports = function (app) {
  overrideUpdateAttributes(app.models.UserUser, ['id', 'created', 'lastLogin', 'deleted', 'deletedAt']);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you call payload represents the target model to update, you can force set the property to undefined and it will be ignored:

```
ctx.instance.items = undefined;
```

If however payload is a property of the model and items is a nested property, you'll either want to ignore payload altogether (set it to undefined) or apply deep merging of the original model payload property and new one after stripping the items off it.